# import all projects from svn repository folder

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have that problem:
I checkout folder (myFolder for example) using tortoise svn.

```
import->existing projects into workspace
```

after it eclipse found a lot of projects(about 50) from different locations of myFolder.

**BUT**
eclipse doesn't understand that these projects from svn(no svn menu if make right click on any file and select team submenu)

I attempt to `import-> team project set` but after it in eclipse I see myfolder only. it is just folder - not projects. I cannot to compile it and use other features.

I think you are understand my problem.

Can you help me?

Comment: You can only import eclipse based projects into eclipse. i.e. projects having .project file configuration of eclipse.

Comment: Can you explain more details?

Comment: Which IDE do you use for your project development? Is it a Java project or webapplication or enterprise application project?

Comment: I use eclipse(sts). I am not sure. I think it is enterprise

Comment: but any humans in our team use idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed a [subversion plugin for eclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) which is is compatible with the version you have for tortoise, i.e the eclipse plugin you actually have - if any - is able to read the `.svn` meta data which was created by the tortoise client. This can happen for example if eclipse plugin is `1.6` and tortoise client is `1.7` or above.

When eclipse shows the ~50 projects deselect all and select only the one(s) you want to import, when passed a folder for importing an existing project, eclipse searches recursively for all folders containing a `.project` file and displays them as projects to be imported. Make a refresh (F5).

**EDIT**

From http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.8_releasenotes.html#compatibility

> **Local Client Compatibility**
>
> Subversion working copies are sometimes accessed using several different clients, e.g. TortoiseSVN, AnkhSVN, and the svn command line client. Because the working copy format has changed with this release, 1.8 clients cannot access an earlier working copy without first upgrading it. Pre-1.8 clients cannot access 1.8 working copies at all and there is no downgrade option

Please upgrade your eclipse svn-kit to the [latest version](http://subclipse.tigris.org/subclipse_1.10.x/changes.html), use this [update site](http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x).

Comment: I want to import all 50

Comment: @gstackoverflow well importing 1, 2 or all projects is not relevant for your actual problem, please consider the first paragraph of my answer. Make sure tortoise ans eclipse plugin are of the same subversion version.

Comment: I use svnkit 1.7 and tortoise svn 1.8

Comment: It was very helpful. I spent a lot of time for resolving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already checkout your projects, import them in eclipse then follow below steps.

Right click on your project go to `Team --> Share Project --> Select Repository type. Do next fill in required information` and it should work.